# Intellij update lost grails project framework - how to recover? No mention of grails anywhere

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea 2016.2.  I had been debugging a Grails 3 project for a week or so.  I allowed Intellij to install updates, and now my project has no idea it's a Grails project.  First clue was that it forgot how to run the application. Then I noticed no Grails View, no Grails console - nothing.  How do I get the Grails framework back?

Comment: Did you try to remove project from the list and reimport it?

Comment: Some help - I ran the Application.groovy file to execute the app. I then closed Intellij and restarted it and most of the Grails artifacts are back.  Still probing to see what is there and what is not.

Comment: Sounds similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349613/grails-application-is-not-found-after-updating-to-intellij-idea-ultimate-2016-2

Answer (score 0):

Rerunning Application.groovy and restarting Intellij seemed to bring back Grails.  Still unsure why, or as to whether I may be missing features, but these steps do work adequately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue & followed these steps which worked for me https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html

> 1. If no project is currently open in IntelliJ IDEA, click Import Project on the Welcome screen. Otherwise, select File | New | Project
>      from Existing Sources.
> 2. In the dialog that opens, select the directory that contains the project to be imported, or a file that contains an appropriate project
>      description. Click OK.
> 3. On the first page of the Import Project wizard, select Gradle, and click Next. (This page is not shown if IntelliJ IDEA has guessed what
>      you are importing.)
> 4. On the next page of the wizard, specify Gradle project settings and global Gradle settings, click Finish.